# Python ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python

input

```
 2 4
 1 2 3 4
 1 0
 2 1
 2 3
```

I need to extract the pairs of numbers from third line to the end(only 2 numbers from the third line)
here is my function

```
def read_nodes():
    n, r = map(int, input().split())
    n_list = []

    for i in range(2 , n):
        n1, n2 = map(int, input().split())
        n_list.append([n1, n2])
    return n_list
print(read_nodes())
```

I except `[[1,0],[2,1],[2,3]]`
but says
`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: input is a matrix ?

Comment: is your input passed as a single line?

Comment: The second line of input is processed by the first iteration of the for loop. The fact that you start your index at `2` does not change that.

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: wow, sorry, I forgot to accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places where this can happen

```
n, r = map(int, input().split())
```

and

```
n1, n2 = map(int, input().split())
```

In both cases you are assuming that the input contains only two values. What if there are 3 or 20? Try something like

```
for x in map(int, input().split()):
    # code here
```

Or wrap the whole thing in try/except so that too many values will be handled cleanly.

Your for loop can probably just be

```
for i in range(2 , n):

    n_list.append(map(int, input().split())
```

Comment: only 2 numbers from the third line

Answer (score 6):

@e4c5 already explained why the error occurs very well, so I am going to skip that part.

If you are using Python 3 and are only interested in the first two values, this is a good opportunity to use [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). Here are some short demos:

```
>>> n1, n2, *other = map(int, input().split())
1 2 3 4
>>> n1
1
>>> n2
2
>>> other
[3, 4]
```

`other` is the "wildcard" name that catches the remaining values.
You can check whether the user provided exactly two values by checking the truthyness of `other`:

```
>>> n1, n2, *other = map(int, input().split())
1 2
>>> if not other: print('exactly two values')
... 
exactly two values
```

Note that this approach will still throw a `ValueError` if the user supplies less than two numbers because we need to unpack at least two from the list `input().split()` in order to assign the names `n1` and `n2`.